# How can I authenticate when using the Bugzilla Perl API in a script?

Tags: perl, authentication, bugzilla

Working from the [Bugzilla API](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Auth.htm), I've written a quick Perl script to clone a Bugzilla Product (recreating all the Components under their new Product). The Bugzilla Perl API is quite easy to use from the command line. I could have just worked on the database directly, but I wanted a longer-term solution. Another option was the webservice, but I thought I'd try using the API directly this time.

The one problem I'm running into is authenticating as my Bz admin user so I can create the new components. Looking at Bugzilla's Bugzilla.pm file, I see that they just run `login()` from a [Bugzilla::Auth](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bugzilla::Auth) object. I'm not sure how to get the username and password in there. I suppose I could just add the script to the Bugzilla admin interface...

Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The Bugzilla API URL above now produces a 404 error.

Comment: Let's refer to the "tip" development version, even though it might not be the exact thing someone wants. http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/ or the main docs page, http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I'm being rather ignorant today, I focused on "web services" and didn't understand what you really wanted.

If you're just using the API to communicate with the database (as opposed to manipulating the database directly), do you really need to authenticate as any user at all?

In the 3.2 source tree, look at `merge-users.pl` for instance, which uses `Bugzilla::User` objects.  Couldn't you do the same with `Bugzilla::Component`?

You should also look at `sanitycheck.pl`, which uses `Bugzilla->set_user`.

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful. I wound up just using Bugzilla->set_user() along with Bugzilla->usage_mode(Bugzilla::Constants::USAGE_MODE_CMDLINE), which let my script copy all the components I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There's been some significant upgrades in the web services capabilities since 3.2, can you upgrade?

In 3.6 at least, check out `contrib/bz_webservice_demo.pl` for how to use the `User.login` method.

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/User.html

Comment: Upgrading is non-trivial due to some local customizations, but I'd like to do it someday. As I look at it, though my real problem using the web services is that I don't see any way to add new Products or Components.

[1]: http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Product.html

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet might enter the question.
Here we check also that the user has the correct "editcomponents" credential.

```
my $user = new Bugzilla::User({ name => $login })
  || ThrowUserError('invalid_username', { name => $login });


# Authenticate using this user account.
Bugzilla->set_user($user);
$user->in_group('editcomponents')
      || ThrowUserError("auth_failure", {group  => "editcomponents",
                                         action => "add",
                                         object => "products"});
```